# why does gnosis doesn't accept my input argument for the set up?

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat, gnosis-safe, multisignature

I'm setting up a safe and when trying to setting it up I'm adding some inputs that look eligible because i checked them with some other codes that were doing the same thing but I get an error on the arguments.

```
export async function createSafe() {
  const { daoMember1, daoMember2, daoMember3, daoMember4 } = await getAccounts()

  // Deploy Gnosis Safe master copy contract
  const masterCopyFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory('GnosisSafe')
  const masterCopy = await masterCopyFactory.deploy()

  // Deploy Gnosis Safe proxy factory contract
  const proxyFactoryFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory('GnosisSafeProxyFactory')
  const proxyFactory = await proxyFactoryFactory.deploy()

  // Create Gnosis Safe contract

  const safeProxy = await proxyFactory.createProxy(masterCopy.address, '0x')
  const safe = await ethers.getContractAt('GnosisSafe', masterCopy.address)

  // Set up Gnosis Safe contract with owners and threshold
  await safe.setup(
    [daoMember1.address],
    1,
    ethers.constants.AddressZero,
    '0x',
    ethers.constants.AddressZero,
    ethers.constants.AddressZero,
    0,
    ethers.constants.AddressZero
  )

  return safe

}
```

```
     Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'GS200'
    at GnosisSafe.addOwnerWithThreshold (@gnosis.pm/safe-contracts/contracts/base/OwnerManager.sol:53)
    at GnosisSafe.setup (contracts/GnosisSafe.sol:86)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async HardhatNode._mineBlockWithPendingTxs (node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/node.ts:1819:23)
    at async HardhatNode.mineBlock (node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/node.ts:508:16)
    at async EthModule._sendTransactionAndReturnHash (node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/modules/eth.ts:1522:18)
    at async HardhatNetworkProvider.request (node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/provider.ts:123:18)
    at async EthersProviderWrapper.send (node_modules/@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers/src/internal/ethers-provider-wrapper.ts:13:20)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a problem with the owner addition process in the Gnosis Safe contract, you only have one owner (`daoMember1.address`) and a threshold of 1. Just replace this part of your code

edit: lets try to get the Safe address from the transaction receipt

```
export async function createSafe() {
  const { daoMember1, daoMember2, daoMember3, daoMember4 } = await getAccounts()

  const masterCopyFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory('GnosisSafe')
  const masterCopy = await masterCopyFactory.deploy()

  const proxyFactoryFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory('GnosisSafeProxyFactory')
  const proxyFactory = await proxyFactoryFactory.deploy()

  const safeProxy = await proxyFactory.createProxy(masterCopy.address, '0x')

  const safeAddress = safeProxy.events[0].args.proxy
  const safe = await ethers.getContractAt('GnosisSafe', safeAddress)

  await safe.setup(
    [daoMember1.address],
    1,
    ethers.constants.AddressZero,
    '0x',
    ethers.constants.AddressZero,
    ethers.constants.AddressZero,
    0,
    ethers.constants.AddressZero
  )

  return safe
}
```

Comment: that is not possible safeProxy is a transaction receipt. I get this error when i do that :Argument of type 'ContractTransaction' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.ts(2769)

Comment: I modified my answer